# How do I pop a value into memory instead of a register? (x86 MASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I want to do something like this `pop QWORD PTR [label]`. How do I do that?

Comment: `pop QWORD PTR [label]` is a valid instruction in 64-bit mode.

Comment: What happened when you tried just doing that?